# How can I browse a website using Javafx Hyperlink type

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently stuck in using Hyperlink type to browse a website in Javafx.

I am required to create a Hyperlink type with a designated name. When I click the link, a website should be popped up.

My code is:

```
@FXML
private Hyperlink labelMin;
```

...

```
public class Item{
...
    public void getPrice();
    public void getUrl(); //I can get the url in string form using this function.
}
```

...

```
if (item.getPrice() < min){
    labelMin.setText(String.valueOf(item.getPrice()));
}
```

The above code correctly displays a hyperlink with text `item.getPrice()`. It is clickable but nothing happens. What can I do in order to browse a website?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
labelMin.setOnAction((event) -> {
    try {
    new ProcessBuilder("browser", "https://google.com").start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

*Url of the website which you want to try should be placed where google's address has been placed.*

Comment: possible but ... why not use the built-in support ;) see the referenced qa in the comment to the question